# Why are formatting methods different for comments?

Tags: support, editing

I noticed that other people can use superscript in comments but

```
<sup>text</sup>
```

doesn't work so how do they do it? I can't find the answer anywhere...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possibilities here:

1. They are using [**MathJax**](//physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation), which enables the Latex-like markdown, is enabled in comments. Specifically, using `$^{2}$` in the comment box would get the appropriate superscript (NB: MathJax is *not* enabled on this Meta site, so you cannot test it).
2. Using [**Unicode**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts) to get the appropriate superscript, e.g. getting x² straight from the linked Wikipedia page.

Unless you know all of the Unicode commands or have a link accessible for copy+paste, it's probably easier to use Option #1.

See also the comments to [this Meta.StackExchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261080/) as well as [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2115/).

Comment: #1 works but it only raises one character. To raise multiple characters put anything after the ^ in curly brackets.

Comment: @mistermarko: That is correct, I've updated to add the curly brace